# C: Mapping the strings to structure fields

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When parsing the HTTP response, I needed to assign the response header values to the matching header fields in the struct. For example,

```
struct http_response {
char* content_type;
char* date;
char* server;
char* via;
char* connection;
char* expires;
};
```

HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 17:30:46 GMT
Server: gws
Expires: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 17:30:46 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/4.11)
Connection: close
```

Mapping

```
http_response->content_type = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http_response->date = "Wed, 10 Jun 2020 17:30:46 GMT"
/* ... */
```

The naive approach is `strcasecmp()`'ing and assigning the values to the struct fields; This seems to be OKish for structs of small size. But I have 35 - 40 fields, and writing 40 `if-else` blocks seem to be a last resort. Taking advantage of the memory layout of the structs, and the homogenous fields (`char*`) can I tweak around to eliminate the `if-else` blocks?

Comment: iassuming the http responses exist in some file you can use the `fscanf()` to read from the file in to the structure alocated buffers. did you try that ?

Comment: Seems that a higher level language than C would do this much more efficiently for you.

Comment: C doesn't have a hash table (associative array) data structure built in, but you can create one fairly easily. That might be a better data structure for you. Here's a quicke example: https://ideone.com/CjCdwi

Comment: @JohnnyMopp POSIX.1-2001 adds [`hcreate()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/hcreate) and related functions to manage hash tables. Granted, it's not in any C standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible alternatives:

## Use a data driven approach

Create a table that maps header field names to [offets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) into `struct http_response`, for example like so:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct table_entry {
    const char *name;
    size_t offset;
};

static const table_entry table[] = {
    {"Content-Type", offsetof(struct table_entry, content_type)},
    {"Date",         offsetof(struct table_entry, date)},
    ...
};
```

And then when parsing each header line, search that table to find the matching field name, and then you know where in the struct to place the value. If you ensure the table is sorted by `key`, then you can use [`bsearch()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch) to find a key in logarithmic time:

```
static int compare_entries(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct table_entry *entry_a = a;
    const struct table_entry *entry_b = b;
    return strcasecmp(entry_a->name, entry_b->name);
}

...

struct http_response response = {NULL};

// Parse a line from the header
char *field = /* header field name */;
char *value = /* value */;

// Search for the key in the table
struct table_entry search_entry = {field};
struct table_entry *match = bsearch(&search_entry, table, sizeof(table) / sizeof(*table), sizeof(*table), compare_entries);

// If it's found, update response
if (match) {
    char **value_ptr = (char **)((char *)&response + match->offset);
    *value_ptr = value;
}
```

## Don't build a struct containing all possible header fields

There are a lot of possible HTTP header fields, but a typical header block will only contain a few of them. It might be more efficient to not build `struct header_field`, but just make a function to query the current header block for a desired field. If you want to do lots of queries on a single header block, then assuming you already have split it into individual lines, you might want to sort the lines using [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) first, so that you can then use `bsearch()` again.

Comment: ``offsetof`` -- It is something I am not aware of. Thank you for letting me know about such a handy macro. I am interested in this strange initialization, ``struct http_response response = {NULL};`` and ``struct table_entry search_entry = {field};``, Wont the compiler complain it you don't initialize the rest of the fields ? What happens to the rest of the fields in such initialization ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table of the headers you are interested in and the byte offsets of the corresponding pointers in the structure. 
Then test if there are matching headers in the HTTP request. If one is found assign it to the structure at the appropriate offset where the corresponding pointer is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct http_response {
char* content_type;
char* date;
char* server;
char* via;
char* connection;
char* expires;
} http_response;

// a type to hold header name and a byte offset in the structure
typedef struct keyval
{
    const char *key;
    size_t offset;
} keyval;

// The headers we are interest in and their byte offsets 
// from the beginning of the structure
static const keyval kv[]  = {
    {"Content-Type", offsetof(http_response, content_type)},
    {"Date", offsetof(http_response, date)},
    {"Server", offsetof(http_response, server)},
    {"Via", offsetof(http_response, via)},
    {"Connection", offsetof(http_response, connection)},
    {"Expires", offsetof(http_response, expires)},

    {NULL, 0}
};

// check each headere line and assign it to the corresponding
// structure field, if it is a header we are interested in
bool assign_header(http_response *resp, const char *hdr_line)
{
    bool found = false;
    char *p = strchr(hdr_line, ':');
    char *pr = (char *)resp;
    if (p)
    {
        int i;
        *p = 0;
        for (i=0; kv[i].key != NULL; i++)
            if (strcmp(kv[i].key, hdr_line) == 0)
            {
                *(char **)(pr + kv[i].offset) = p + 1;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
    }
    return found;
}

// test code
int main()
{
    int i;
    http_response resp;
    char test[] = 
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n\
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 17:30:46 GMT\n\
Server: gws\n\
Expires: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 17:30:46 GMT\n\
Cache-Control: private\n\
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/4.11)\n\
Connection: close\n\
";
    memset(&resp, 0, sizeof(resp));
    char *rest = test;
    char *p =strtok_r(test, "\n", &rest);
    while (p)
    {
        assign_header(&resp, p);
        p =strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &rest);
    }

    // test a few fields
    printf("Content-Type => %s\n", resp.content_type);
    printf("Server => %s\n", resp.server);
    printf("Expires => %s\n", resp.expires);

    return 0;
}
```

After posting, I see an answer with similar logic has also been posted :)

The above code assigns pointers to the structure. You may want to modify it to assign allocated copies of the values instead and later write a function to free all the allocated memory.